# How can I print the total number of file descriptors with index 24

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

How can I print the total number of file descriptors with index 24 for all the running processes?

I tried something: $

```
ls /proc/*/fd 2> errors.txt > stdout.txt | grep "^24" stdout.txt | wc -l
```

This solution returns 0 everytime.

I mention that my task ask me to write an one liner in order to solve it.

Comment: [Please do not post the same question on all Stack Exchange.](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169544/how-to-print-total-number-of-file-descriptors-with-index-24)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is cross-posted: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169544/how-to-print-total-number-of-file-descriptors-with-index-24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls /proc/*/fd 2>/dev/null | grep -c '^24$'
```